# Extracting IP address from a line from ifconfig output with grep

Tags: regex, grep

Given this specific line pulled from `ifconfig`, in my case:

`inet 192.168.2.13 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255`

How could one extract the `192.168.2.13` part (the local IP address), presumably with regex?

Comment: This was only gonna be used on an internal network where I knew that I would be using IPv4.

Comment: You might try my suggestion posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389565/249079

Comment: Have a look at my answer in unix stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389565/249079

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Here's one way using `grep`:**

```
line='inet 192.168.2.13 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.256'

echo "$line" | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
```

Results:

```
192.168.2.13
192.168.2.256
```

---

**If you wish to select only valid addresses, you can use:**

```
line='inet 192.168.0.255 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.256'

echo "$line" | grep -oE "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
```

Results:

```
192.168.0.255
```

---

**Otherwise, just select the fields you want using `awk`, for example:**

```
line='inet 192.168.0.255 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.256'

echo "$line" | awk -v OFS="\n" '{ print $2, $NF }'
```

Results:

```
192.168.0.255
192.168.2.256
```

---

---

Addendum:

[Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `\b`

Comment: Thanks very much, but this matches the `broadcast` too

Comment: @JJ56, perhaps using `awk` is the better option then

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, `egrep` would suffice. I have edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: This matches >256 the answer is wrong. You need to match < 255.

Comment: @MichaelTomkins: AFAIK, ifconfig will never produce an invalid address. If you are trying to grep from a text file containing pseudo-IP addresses, you would usually want to validate them anyway, by checking that they exist on your network. If you just want to select only technically valid addresses, then I've added some code to do that. Please see above.

Comment: Ahh, the right answer, and the better right answer. With a limited input (ifconfg) the pattern is correct.

Comment: Nice regexp, but did you tested it?
 It doesn't match 200.1.1.1, 1.240.1.1, 1.1.255.1. Only last number could be more than 199 and I can't see a flaw in regexp.

Comment: @Drey: Not extensively tested. The literal dot before `{3}` was being treated as part of the number sequence. Adding another set of parentheses in the right place seems to fix it. Can you confirm that that works?

Comment: @Steve, yes, now it works like a charm! Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 5):

use this regex `((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?=\s*netmask)`

Comment: Once again, unless I'm doing something wrong this gives the whole line

Answer (score 4):

you can use egrep (which is basically the same as grep -E)
in egrep there are named groups for character classes, e.g.: "digit"
(which makes the command longer in this case - but you get the point...)

another thing that is good to know is that you can use **brackets** to **repeat** a pattern

```
ifconfig | egrep '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

or

```
ifconfig | egrep '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

if you only care about the actual IP address use the parameter **-o** to limit output to the **matched pattern** instead of the whole line:

```
ifconfig | egrep -o '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}'
```

...and if you don't want BCast addresses and such you may use this grep:

```
ifconfig | egrep -o 'addr:([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | egrep -o '[[:digit:]].*'
```

*I assumed you were talking about IPv4 addresses only*

Comment: Thank you! Going one small step further, to get the wlan0 address: ifconfig | egrep -o 'addr:192.([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){2}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | egrep -o '[[:digit:]].*' That worked, I tried to do avoid using 192 and do a more generic ifconfig | egrep -o 'wlan0*addr:([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | egrep -o '[[:digit:]].*' but that didn't work... any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some alternative way:

```
ip addr | grep -Po '(?!(inet 127.\d.\d.1))(inet \K(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})'
```

it will print out all the IPs but the localhost one.

Answer (score 3):

`[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`

Comment: Sorry, but how would I put this into grep? Using `echo '[the line]' | grep -P '[your answer]'` gives me the whole line :\

Comment: you match 3 digit separeted by dot, this is not ip, and you catch broadcast

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment, but I found a bug in Steve's "select only valid addresses" regex.  I don't quite understand the problem, but I believe I have found the fix.  The first command demonstrates the bug; the second one demonstrates the fix:

```
$ echo "test this IP: 200.1.1.1" |grep -oE "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
$ echo "test this IP: 200.1.1.1" |grep -oE "\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
200.1.1.1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`. First instruction deletes all characters until first digit in the line, and second instruction saves first IP in group 1 (`\1`) and replaces all the line with it:

```
sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//; s/\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: This will print invalid ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This code works nicely and easy too.

```
ifconfig | grep Bcast > /tmp/ip1
cat /tmp/ip1 | awk '{ print $2 }' > /tmp/ip2
sed -i 's/addr://' /tmp/ip2
IPADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/ip2)
echo "$IPADDRESS"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this, one sed command, just for sports:

```
    ip -o -4 addr show dev eth0 | sed 's/.* inet \([^/]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me on *raspberry pi zero w*.

(extract **wlan0: inet *192.168.x.y*** address from `ifconfig` output)

Search for pattern 'inet 192' in *ifconfig* output  and get the 10th position using *space* delimiter.

```
 $> ifconfig |grep 'inet 192'|cut -d' ' -f10
```

Output:
**192.168.1.6**

Comment: best practice is to condense the space with the `tr` command `ifconfig |grep 'inet 192'|  tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2`

Answer (score 0):

If using grep that supports Perl regex:

```
(your command that pulls mentioned line) | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d\.]+'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select the column with `awk`, e.g.:

```bash
echo "inet 192.168.2.13 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255" | awk '{print $2}'
```

This also works with the full output of `ifconfig`:

```bash
ifconfig | grep broadcast | awk '{print $2}'
```