# sed - How to extract IP address using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

This is for an assignment so I have no choice but to use sed.

Given a file *messages*, how can I extract all the IP addresses and print them?

I first tried

```
sed -n '/((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/p' messages
```

But it printed nothing. After doing some research, I found out that sed does not support non-greedy operators like ? and |.

I've been wracking my brain but I can't think of a way to do this without the non-greedy operators. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `sed -r`.  It does support what you're talking about.

Comment: Thanks so much, works great. Guess I didn't do enough research.

Comment: Remember that the `-r` flag is a `GNU sed` extension. It won't work with other seds.

Comment: Note that your regex will allow `09.08.07.06` through as a valid IP address.  Classic (POSIX) [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) doesn't support ERE's using the `|` operator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `sed -r` (extended regex) or escape the capture groups with `\`

Answer (score 46):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) will be more suitable there (if you have `sed`, you should have `grep` too):

```
grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' messages
```

This is your own `regex` with no modification (tested OK).

[image: note]
But a more proper way to parse IP without complicated regex in a reliable way, with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -nE 'say $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/' messages
```

Works also for [ipv6](/questions/tagged/ipv6):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -nE 'say $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv6})/' messages
```

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but the OP did say that he must use `sed`. So that's probably the reason. However, I do agree with you, `grep` would be more appropriate than `sed -n '/.../p`.

Comment: Actually, there is one difference. And it's hard to discern what the OP is actually trying to do. Your `grep` code will return the IP addresses only. The OP may actually be trying to match and print lines containing IP address. That could be the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Thanks! I never paid attention to `-o` grep option and always used `sed` for extraction, while it looks like in most cases I could just use `grep` !

Answer (score 17):

If you have `GNU sed`, you could simply add the `-r` flag to use EREs:

```
sed -rn '/((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])/p' file
```

Otherwise, you will need to escape certain characters:

```
sed -n '/\(\(1\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)\.\)\{3\}\(1\?[0-9][0-9]\?\|2[0-4][0-9]\|25[0-5]\)/p' file
```

These characters include:

- groups using parenthesis: `(`, `)`
- occurrence braces: `{`, `}`
- 'or' pipes: `|`
- non-greedy question marks: `?`

Generally (although not for your case) I use the following to match IP address:

```
sed -rn '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/p' file
```

Or in compatibility mode:

```
sed -n '/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/p' file
```

Comment: None above work for `echo ksjbfjasbhdf10.0.0.10sckksjdnc > file`

Comment: @MaximKostrikin: These [tag:sed] commands will print the entire line if they contain an IP address. To extract only valid IP addresses, I would usually use one of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483005/751863

Answer (score 2):

You can do that too:

Windows:

```
ipconfig | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1' | sed '2 d' | head -n1;
```

OSX/Linux:

```
ifconfig | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1' | sed '1 d' | head -n1;
```

reference: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun

- `-n`: Places a non-printing loop around your command.
- `-l`: Enables automatic line-ending processing
- `-e`: Allows you to provide the program as an argument rather than in a file.

Comment: It would be better if you add some explanation for these commands, such as the `perl` command

Comment: `ifconfig | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1' | sed '1 d'` works well

Comment: Better use my solution: `perl -MRegexp::Common -nE 'say $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/'` in my response. No need so many pipes

Answer (score 0):

If you use `git-bash` on `Windows`. It is quite handy.

```
 export LC_ALL=C; ipconfig | sed -n 's/IPv4//gp;' | sed -En 's/.*(10.*)/\1/gp'
```

```
以太网适配器 VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   连接特定的 DNS 后缀 . . . . . . . :
   本地链接 IPv6 地址. . . . . . . . : fe80::3177:bf7b:590:c787%6
   IPv4 地址 . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.1
   子网掩码  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   默认网关. . . . . . . . . . . . . :

以太网适配器 VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   连接特定的 DNS 后缀 . . . . . . . :
   本地链接 IPv6 地址. . . . . . . . : fe80::c8de:747e:34fe:58cd%12
   IPv4 地址 . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.239.1
   子网掩码  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   默认网关. . . . . . . . . . . . . :

以太网适配器 以太网:

   连接特定的 DNS 后缀 . . . . . . . : some.com
   本地链接 IPv6 地址. . . . . . . . : fe80::9d9:bb4d:e77a:3a98%15
   IPv4 地址 . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.11.68.42
   子网掩码  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   默认网关. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.11.168.1
```

The script will only give you the `10` prefixed `ip` address `10.11.68.42`.

The script can be explained to be

> match lines contain `IPv4` and substitute `IPv4` with blank and print,
> then capture something prefixed with `10` and print it

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin:

```bash
ping -n 1 www.ip.com | sed  -n '2,/[0-9]/ s/.*\( [0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\{3\}\).*/\1/p' | tr -d ' '
```