# How to extract the month, day of month and IP address from the line using sed or awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have extracted the day/month and IP that are continuously bruteforcing my IMAP server:

```
Nov1 unknown[186.216.99.239]:
Nov1 unknown[62.249.196.214]:
Nov1 unknown[110.145.123.120]:
Nov1 fixed-187-190-251-149.totalplay.net[187.190.251.149]:
Nov1 pd9568164.dip0.t-ipconnect.de[217.86.129.100]:
Nov1 unknown[103.227.88.130]:
```

I want the output to be like below:

```
Nov1 186.216.99.239
Nov1 62.249.196.214
Nov1 110.145.123.120
Nov1 187.190.251.149
Nov1 217.86.129.100
Nov1 103.227.88.130
```

I achieved this result using combination of sed, awk and cut with below code, but I would like to learn if there are better ways?

```
while read -r line
    do 
        monthday=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')
        # ip=$(echo $line | awk -F'[\\\[\\\]]' { print $2 } ) 
        ip=$(echo $line| cut -d[ -f2| cut -d] -f1 )
        echo "${monthday} ${ip}"
    done < badIpList.txt
```

Comment: You could extract the IP address using one of the commands listed in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928573/sed-how-to-extract-ip-address-using-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]\\[\\]]' '{print $1,$3}' file
```

- `-F'[[:space:]\\[\\]]'` - complex field separator, either whitespace `[:space:]` or `[` or `]`. Thereby, the line, for ex. `Nov1 unknown[186.216.99.239]:` will be divided into fields: 1) `Nov1`, 2) `unknown`, 3) `186.216.99.239` and 4) `:`

The output:

```
Nov1 186.216.99.239
Nov1 62.249.196.214
Nov1 110.145.123.120
Nov1 187.190.251.149
Nov1 217.86.129.100
Nov1 103.227.88.130
```

Comment: i find it simple and easy on eyes :) would you mind describing it a little?

Comment: @satch_boogie, yes, see my explanation

Answer (score 4):

With awk: set the field separator to the any of space, `[` or `]`, then print the first and third field:

```
$ awk -F "[][ ]" '{ print $1, $3 }' infile
Nov1 186.216.99.239
Nov1 62.249.196.214
Nov1 110.145.123.120
Nov1 187.190.251.149
Nov1 217.86.129.100
Nov1 103.227.88.130
```

Notice that the field separator is a regular expression, namely the bracket expression `[][ ]`. From the [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions):

> To include one of the characters `\`, `]`, `-`, or `^` in a bracket expression, put a `\` in front of it.

So the expression would have to be

```
[\[\] ]
```

but because regular expressions stored in strings ("[dynamic/computed regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps)") are scanned *twice*, we have to escape the backslash:

```
-F '[\\[\\] ]'
```

or to use double quotes, as I did, I'd have to escape both the backslash and the backslash escaping it:

```
-F "[\\\[\\\] ]"
```

which clearly isn't all too readable. Thankfully, there is a loophole:

> Additionally, if you place `]` right after the opening `[`, the closing bracket is treated as one of the characters to be matched.

so we get away with

```
-F "[][ ]"
```

even within double quotes. There is no real reason to use double quotes here, by the way.

Comment: w Thanks i had this question in my mind about "[ ][ ]" for ages and now its cleared cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sed -E 's/\s.*\[(.*)\]:/ \1/' file
```

no loops needed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple with this sed:

```
$ sed -r 's|^([^ ]*)[^[]*\[([^]]*)\].*|\1 \2|' badIpList.txt
Nov1 186.216.99.239
Nov1 62.249.196.214
Nov1 110.145.123.120
Nov1 187.190.251.149
Nov1 217.86.129.100
Nov1 103.227.88.130
```

Logic: Print the first word and the contents of the square bracket.