# pulling lines with boot/reboot proccess and lines with IP address

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, scripting

I need this for linux bash scripting on a Ubuntu based OS.

So I've look but everything pulls IPs as long as it has its own column. however the log file I have does not have that. This is the format of the log:

```
5937 Aug  2 05:39:38 CentOSBind lvm: 2 logical volume(s) in volume group "cl" now active
5938 Aug  2 05:39:38 CentOSBind systemd: Started LVM2 PV scan on device 8:2.
5939 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind kernel: IPv6: ens33: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::8bfa:9934:7f07:9484 detected!
5940 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Registering new address record for fe80::8bfa:9934:7f07:9484 on ens33.*.
5941 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind NetworkManager[725]: <info>  [1501673979.0967] device (ens33): ipv6: duplicate address check failed for the fe80::8bfa:9934:7f07:9484/64 lft forever pref forever lifetime 2-0[4294967295,4294967295] dev 2 flags tentative,permanent,0x8 src kernel address
5942 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.15.150 on ens33.
5943 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Withdrawing workstation service for ens33.
5944 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Withdrawing workstation service for lo.
5945 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Host name conflict, retrying with CentOSBind-2
5946 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Registering new address record for fe80::8bfa:9934:7f07:9484 on ens33.*.
5947 Aug  2 05:39:39 CentOSBind avahi-daemon[677]: Registering new address record for 192.168.15.150 on ens33.IPv4.
```

What I need to do is to pull each individual line with an IPv4 and IPv6 address and pull lines that indicate a system start up or reboot.
Additionally I want to be able to geolocate each IP and get a country count. I have yet to find anything that allows me to do both. Guidance would be very appreciated, then code since I'm still relatively new to scripting.

Comment: Ryan, first, bash is bash as long as it is running on Linux (there are subtle differences between bash 3.X and bash 4.X, but none relevant here). The `CentOSBind` suggests you are running CentOS (which isn't really a Ubuntu based OS..., but that too is irrelevant) You are not going to find "anything" that will both 'geolocate each IP and get a country count' -- it is up to you to put the pieces together to do that. Which "log" are you pulling from? Something in `/var/log`, or the suggestion of `systemd` indicates that you will want to look at `journalctl`.

Comment: the current OS im useing is BackBox which is a ubuntu based OS. i am refering to linux bash because windows has a bash funtion as well and does not run the same way. the CentOSBind is just something in the log file and as for which log file it does not matter. the script im trying to run should not matter what the file is it should run like ./script.sh filename.exention as for geting geolocation and country count im aware that there is no single commend for that. thats why im calling this a "script" i have the idivial commands to do that but i need guidence on being able to grab the ip

Comment: from the file put that in the geoip command, then take the results from that and make a count of what country and and repeat this until no more IPs are found.

Comment: it also accurse to me people down vote the post either because i have no understanding of what im asking or the lake of information that i have provided. i think people should be more up front ans aks what true the issue then jump to conclusions. these down vote hurt my rep and in turns when i need to ask a question to get help im unable to and i lose work either because i cant find the answer or no one want guide me in the right direction

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I suspect that it is due to the clarity of the question. Don't worry about downvotes, it all comes out in the wash over time, just make sure you have the integrity to leave a comment if you downvote a question. To find an IPV4 address in the log, you can use, `grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' logfile`. You can search here for IPV6 Regex's (regular expressions). You may need to call `sort | uniq` to remove duplicates from the output, you can read the IPV4 address into an array with `array=($(grep -o regex logfile | sort | uniq))`.

Comment: thank this is actully very help full   #!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r -a LINE
do
    grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*'
 array=($(grep -o regex | sort | uniq))
done < "$1" 
this is what i have so for as for this is to be able to read any log that is fed in to it. and as you said the ips should be assigned in the array?

Comment: `while read -r line; do array+=(grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' <<<"$line"); ## do more stuff; done < logfile` (**note:** the `<<<` which is a **herestring** allowing redirection of a variable to `grep`) If you cannot use a *herestring*, just pipe `line` to `grep`, e.g. `array+=(echo "$line" | grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*)'`

Comment: Or, if you want to just process the addresses `while read -r IP; do # do something with IP; done < <(grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' logfile)` which uses *process substitution* to feed only the IP's to your `while` loop. **note:** that is `<space<(command)`

Comment: so if im getting this right the grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' gets eahc ip and assigns it to an array with the array+=() how ever im alittle unclear what a herestring is could you explain this alittle bit?

Comment: ok so this allows me to run a command with the results of something kinda like the | but going in the oppisite direction?

Comment: Normally you would have to use `echo $line | grep -o regex`, because `grep` operates on **files** (or input from `stdin`), not **variables**. A *herestring* allows you to have the content of a **variable** redirected as **file** input (on `stdin`) so `grep` doesn't puke and it saves spawning a two additional subshell (one for `echo` and one for the pipe `|` ) that would normally be required. However, it is a **bashism** only available in bash, not POSIX shell.

Comment: Also note, if you enclose your code in comments in `backticks` (e.g. `\`...\``) it will be shown in a fixed font with the off-white background `:)`

Comment: oh i think i understand. thank you. and i appreciate that bit of info too

Comment: If I were starting a script in bash to process unique IPV4 addresses from your logfile (I saved it in `iplog.txt`), I would start with: `while read -r IP; do printf "my IP is %s\n" "$IP"; done < <(grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' iplog.txt | sort | uniq)` which outputs `my IP is 192.168.15.150` Of course, you would add your IP processing in the loop below `printf "my IP is %s\n" "$IP"`.

Comment: will this also be able to let me run a command to each of those IPs as well? as i said i want to be able to use 'geoip $IP |' something to grab a single part of that results or count just one bit of info

Comment: Sure, where I use `printf`, you can put as many different commands as you want that operate on `"$IP"`. Once you have the ip in `$IP` you can process it as many ways as you want. If you want to save an array of ip's just use something like `ipv4arr+=("$IP")` in the loop and you can work on the contents of the array as many time as you like later on in the script with `for ip in "${ipv4arr[@]}"; do # whatever else; printf "my IP is STILL %s\n" "$ip"; done`.

Comment: If you just want to read all IPv4 addresses into an array first, and then process them from the array, you can do, e.g. `ipv4=($(grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' iplog.txt | sort | uniq))`. Then you can process each IP with `for ip in "${ipv4[@]}"; do printf "my IP is %s\n" "$ip"; done` which gives the same `my IP is 192.168.15.150`. There are always multiple ways to approach a problem in bash -- as you learn them, you will get a feel for what is best for whatever the task at hand may be. It's worth spending a few hours playing with the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide

Comment: awesome this works like a charm.

Comment: additionally. i have a string that i want to search for. but i want to print the full line if the string is in the line  ive used "grep -n 'STRING' filename" and this doesnt work. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That should work fine. `-n` just dumps the line number it is found on - before the full line. Now `grep` (as all Linux everything) is *case-sensitive*. So if it is `'String'` instead of `'STRING'`, it won't be found. In that case use the `-i` option, e.g. `grep -in 'string' filename`.

Answer (score 0):

grep with regex should help you to get IP address,

[Extracting IP address from a line from ifconfig output with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482951/extracting-ip-address-from-a-line-from-ifconfig-output-with-grep)

find country by IP:

http://xmodulo.com/geographic-location-ip-address-command-line.html

Comment: thank you i appreciate the help however. the first link does not give me any code that words. and the secound link telling me nothing i already know